# C - Code does not return to main after timer interrurpt

Tags: c, timer, embedded, stm32

I am using stm32f103 microprossesor on our custom design board. I used timer interrupt for setting a bool variable to true in every 10ms. I check value of the bool variable in the main loop and if this variable is true, I toggle a led on board on every 500ms.

Although, timer interrupt flag cleared after finishing setting true operation, the code does not return to the main loop and led is not toggled. Timer initialize, interrupt and main loop as follows.

```
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 7199;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 99;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
      /* Initialization Error */
      Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-2- Start the TIM Base generation in interrupt mode ####################*/
  /* Start Channel1 */
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
      Error_Handler();
  }
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim2);
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    task = true;
}
```

The main loop

```
while (1)
{
    if(task == true)
    {
        task_timer++;

        if(task_timer % 50 == 0)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_15);
        }
        task = false;
    }
}
```

When I use else if statement in the main loop, code is processed as expected.

```
while (1)
{
    if(task == true)
    {
        task_timer++;

        if(task_timer % 50 == 0)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_15);
        }
        task = false;
    }
    else if(task == false)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Interestingly, if I used only else statement, also code works unstable.

Is there anyone can explain the cause of this.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see any code where you have configured the timer and its interrupt, I wonder how interrupt will be generated in this code.
Have you checked if your ISR is getting serviced by toggling another GPIO in it and check it on DSO?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. In particular show how you have declared the `task` variable.

Comment: Is variable `task` declared as `volatile`?

Comment: Added timer initialize code. I already checked pin and port of led. Also, I can toggled led as expected with my second main loop. `task` decleared `uint8_t` and extern in other c files. @GauravPathak

Comment: Declare `task` as `volatile`.

Comment: @GürtaçKadem So, it means that your code works only when you use `else if` after `if`.
When you use `if` and after that `else if` then the first `if` condition gets satisfied and the LED blinks but when you use only `if` LED doesn't blink. Is this the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Yes, it is true. @GauravPathak

Comment: I see.
Please turn off compiler optimization if any and then try to execute the program.
In Second tryout as per @kaylum suggestion try declaring `task` as volatile and use `-O2` compiler optimization.

Comment: Use the debugger, see if it reaches the interrupt handler and single-step it. You can stop the timer during debug-halt in the DBG module.

Comment: @GauravPathak, you are right. Turning off compiler optimization is solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @GürtaçKadem But turning OFF optimization is not a solution. Try to find the solution.
I think declaring the variable task as volatile with optimization ON should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off all compiler optimizations in settings.

Comment: Turning off compiler optimization is solve the issue.

Comment: @Adwait Patil I think compiler will treat volatile variable normally if optimization is turned OFF. So, if variable is declared as volatile then compiler optimization should be ON otherwise it will treat the variable normally.